# Parse UTF-8 encoded JSON from DB into JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, encoding, utf-8

I have the following column in my database with UTF-8 encoded letters:

- **chineseWords**

  nǐ  hǎo

console.log(value) gives: `null`

---

If I change them to non UTF-8,

- **chineseWords**

  ni hao

console.log(value) gives: `ni hao`

---

If I just keep one word

- **chineseWords**

  nǐ

console.log(value) gives: `n?`

---

**jQuery:**

```
function getData (functionToRun) {  
    $.getJSON("phpscripts.php", {"_functionToRun" : functionToRun},
        function (returned_data) {                      
            var value = returned_data.chineseWords;         
            console.log(value);
        }
    );
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$qry = 
    'SELECT * 
    FROM tasks
    WHERE npc_id_fk = 1';

$result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Why would the browser be outputting `null` and `n?`?

---

**EDIT:** following [this blog on encoding and decoding UTF-8](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html), I tried:

`console.log(decodeURIComponent(value));` //output: `n?`

---

**EDIT 2:**

**Connect:**

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (Error code: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . ")... " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
?>
```

Start of my `phpscripts.php` file:

```
<?php
include 'runDB.php';
mysql_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
```

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: JS has no problem parsing a UTF8 string.

Comment: @cookiemonster Do you know why it's outputting `null` then?

Comment: No, I have no idea. HTTP headers not properly set maybe?

Comment: Maybe try making a native XHR request and look at the response text to see if it's what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML Header add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

In your PHP Mysql call add:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connectToDBVar);
```

after your db mysql_connect but before your query